# Need tips on creativity and inspiration

Tags: animation, freelance, video

I am getting into motion graphics, video editing, some 2d and 3d, compositing (the whole vfx pack). I am getting good at handling the software I am using, and have completed a bunch of tutorials and mini courses (freebies). I want to get into more serious projects and particularly to work as a freelancer, creating 2d intros for people, editing templates, 2d motion graphics for channels or plain video editing.

The problem is I am not a particularly creative individual. I can't seem to have any good sources of inspiration and don't have lots of great ideas. This is why I favor compositing, cause i get to put things together that are made by other people. I enjoy every part of creating and editing, but i don't seem to create a whole bunch. Getting into the business of logo/banner design honestly scares me a bit. But its something I wanna slowly get into, so i would appreciate any advice.

For those of you who have worked professionally, how did you deal with the pressure when you first started? Although I think I am sufficiently trained, I feel as though I am totally unprepared for a real world paid job and that I'll fail a customer. What level of skills is required to work at a platform like upwork of fiverr or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the work of others.  Also, just as a side note: video editing questions are off-topic here. Probably better to ask at the [Video Production Stack Exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), although this question might be too broad even for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not a great question. I feel it is overly broad and opinion based. It may be put on hold as such.

However, my *opinion*....

---

It's actually very simple, and the same premise can be used throughout an entire career....

**Never take on any project you are not 150% certain you can complete.**

If that means you start with very small, minimal, tasks then that's what it means. As you gain experience, knowledge, and confidence *what* you are capable of will increase, and so will the complexity of projects you can tackle.

There is *never* any harm in informing a client that what they want is not your bailiwick or may be beyond your capabilities. In fact, it's it often better to be up front than to try and get something done which you have no clue how to do.

---

For what it's worth.. I don't think you'll *ever* really get ahead using crowd sourcing web sites such as fivr or upwork. The simple structure of those sites, and similar sites, are *never* favorable to the artist/creative and *absolutely* do *nothing* to help foster a "business" other than their own. Word of mouth and local networking will typically yield *much* better connections and subsequent clients/work.

Comment: Yes, the question is pretty subjective but I want to hear different opinions and experiences so thanks for your reply. I live on a small island in Greece so I don't think there's a lot i can do on local networking. Would you recommend anything else besides these 2 platforms?

Comment: Well, that's kind of the thing. If I wanted to be a 5 star chef I could never do that effectively in a small town. I would need to live in a mid-sized area with enough people to warrant the *need* for a chef of that stature. There are some professions which are not geared toward success in very small towns. But, with that being posted, success is relative. What is more than enough for some is woefully lacking to others. So really, where you want to go, career wise, all depends upon you and *may* mean there would be a need to relocate. You are rarely *obligated* to stay where you are born.

Comment: It is possible to make some money on the crowdsourcing sites with enough patience and effort. But, in my opinion, you can't really grow a "business" based solely upon those sites. It seems to me, their users are always "chasing" the next paycheck rather it coming to them.

Answer (score 0):

I've a thought which may well already have occurred to you, but nonetheless:

Create a presence on sites like Behance, ArtStation, Deviant Art, Dribble, UI Movement, UX Planet, even Medium - but... *especially* for **VFX** *and* compositing, I'd look at ***ArtStation***.

**Self-assign projects:** make them reasonably realistic in terms of final deliverables expectations, timelines, and available initial resources - then actually go through the whole process for each one, including all the intermediate steps - and when reviewing, be critical and give yourself realistic edits and revisions. Post the results as "self-commissioned" work - if the in-process docs are good enough, include them in your posting.

This not only gives you portfolio pieces to show, it gets you comfortable with your proposed process and pipeline, and even allows you a window into what your client's experience will be like with your currently-proposed process - and also gives you a shakedown OF that process, allowing you to optimise it ***without*** the post-mortem involving the "lesson-learned" of "I lost a valuable client who will never return" - which many of us faced early in our career paths, and is never an easy one to accept.

On **ArtStation** often creatives will collaborate on self-commissioned works, and as many are 3D modelers or renderers, you could well do some collaborative work where you are the final compositor for some short, but innovative piece - then you ***both*** end up with portfolio quality pieces and more experience with collaborating and the inevitable technical hurdles that encompasses - and again, without putting a paying client in the non-academic-world learning-curve grinder, this is a win-win.

Hope this helps.